Set the X axis colored rgba(255,0,0,0.5) in amcharts 5 line graph
Actually I have this part of code for defining the X (I mean the y=0) axis.
// Create axes
// https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v5/charts/xy-chart/axes/
var xRenderer = am5xy.AxisRendererX.new(root, {});
var xAxis = chart.xAxes.push(
  am5xy.CategoryAxis.new(root, {
    categoryField: "milestone_short",
    renderer: xRenderer,
    tooltip: am5.Tooltip.new(root, {
      pointerOrientation: "horizontal",
      labelText: "{milestone_long}"
    })
  })
);


xRenderer.grid.template.setAll({
  location: 1
})

xAxis.data.setAll(data);

I'm trying like everything to make the X axis rgba(255,0,0,0.5) colored.
But even if there are some codepen and with the help of GPTs or gemnini It seems it doesn't work.
I miss the good old times where amcharts element was just a big JSON code with all the settings that can be changed in one place.
Tried the following code but it didn't work.
// Create axes
// https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v5/charts/xy-chart/axes/
var xRenderer = am5xy.AxisRendererX.new(root, {});

var xAxis = chart.xAxes.push(
  am5xy.CategoryAxis.new(root, {
    categoryField: "milestone_short",
    renderer: xRenderer,
    tooltip: am5.Tooltip.new(root, {
      pointerOrientation: "horizontal",
      labelText: "{milestone_long}"
    })
  })
);

// Define the grid configuration after the xRenderer is likely initialized
xRenderer.grid = am5.Grid.new(root, {
  template: {
    setAll: {
      location: 1 // Set location to 1 for the zero grid line
    },
    states: {
      create: "gridLineStyle"
    }
  }
});

var gridLineStyle = xRenderer.grid.template.states.create("gridLineStyle");
gridLineStyle.set("stroke", am5.Color.getInstance().set({ r: 255, g: 0, b: 0, a: 0.5 })); // Set red color with transparency

xAxis.data.setAll(data); // Assuming you have your data prepared

It seems that the object isn't initialized.
